# Cheap 128x64 OLED

Tags: i2c, raspbian-stretch, lcd

I purchased two cheap OLED modules, one is 0.96" 128x32 I2C at the following link:
https://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B06XRBTBTB/

and the other is a 2.4" 128x64 at the following link:
https://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B0749DYGSW/

I got the first to work with the Adafruit SSD1306 library (I followed [this](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2018/04/i2c-oled-display-module-with-raspberry-pi/) guide).
The problem comes with the second one, 'cause I cannot understand if it requires I2C or SPI. I tried to wire only 4 of it's 7 pin in I2C mode (VCC, GND, SDA, SCL) like the first, but it's not working (**i2cdetect -y 1** command does not show any attached device). I also tried to follow [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/ssd1306-oled-displays-with-raspberry-pi-and-beaglebone-black/wiring) guide and wire it in SPI mode, but with no result. Did someone managed to make this kind of OLED work? The pins on this module are the following:

- CS
- DC
- RES
- SDA
- SCL
- VCC
- GND

Comment: It might be a 5V module.

Comment: it's a 3.0 to 5.5V. I connected it to the 5V pin.

Comment: That's the problem. The Raspi is a 3.3V device and wants 3.3V on its GPIO socket I²C pins exclusively. The only 5V I²C it has is on the HDMI connector.

Comment: Well, I tried to connect it to the 3.3V pin, still not working.